# tf.conv2d gaussian kernel convolution gives strange border effect in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gaussian, convolution

Currently my code is succeeding in visualizing the deeper layers of a network via activation maximization. However, in order to get a more interpretable image, I'm experimenting with different regularization methods. currently I'm regularizing via a Gaussian convolution. See Understanding Neural Networks Through Deep Visualization by Yosinski .

To do this I've added a Gaussian loss to my loss function. I'm using Python & Tensorflow. The Gaussian loss is calculated by (each iteration) subtracting a blurred image from the current image, and thereby steering the network towards producing a more blurry final image.

First a Gaussian kernel is made of size 4x4.
Then, I perform a convolution with this kernel for each color channel through tf.conv2d with the code: (gauss_var is the gaussian kernel with dimension [4, 4, 1, 1])

```
# unstack 3 channel image
[tR, tG, tB] = tf.unstack(input_image, num=3, axis=3)
# give each one a fourth dimension in order to use it in conv2d
tR = tf.expand_dims(tR, 3)
tG = tf.expand_dims(tG, 3)
tB = tf.expand_dims(tB, 3)

#convolve each input image with the gaussian filter
tR_gauss = tf.nn.conv2d(tR, gauss_var, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
tG_gauss = tf.nn.conv2d(tG, gauss_var, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
tB_gauss = tf.nn.conv2d(tB, gauss_var, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

I calculate the difference by doing:

```
# calculate difference
R_diff = tf.subtract(tR, tR_gauss)
G_diff = tf.subtract(tR, tG_gauss)
B_diff = tf.subtract(tR, tB_gauss)
```

And make it into one number:

```
total_diff = tf.add_n([R_diff, G_diff, B_diff])
gaussian_loss = tf.reduce_sum(total_diff)
```

The problem is that the resulting image always shows bars at the borders, and is colored blueish. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyvok.png) is an over-exaggerated example of a final image.

I'm pretty sure this bordering effect has something to do with conv2d, but I don't know how to change it. So far I've tried using different kernel sizes, and although the borders change, they still remain. Changing padding from 'SAME' to 'VALID' results in different output dimensions which is also problematic. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I'm sorry no one answered your question.  I'm no expert, but I'll give it a try.  First, there is no perfect solution.

The easiest way is to look at tf.pad.  That has a couple of modes that allows you to grow your images by copying the edges.  Or, you may need to resort to tf.tile.  The padding amount should match your kernel 1/2width. Then use 'VALID' for padding and you will get an output smaller but the same size as your input.

For a better, yet more difficult solution, you can work in the frequency domain.  Convert the images to frequency domain.  Then zero out some of the *higher* frequencies and then return to the space domain.

Hopefully you have already solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with ugly borders around my output image.

I found out that the `padding='SAME'` option of `conv2d` adds zeros to the outside of the image.

In my case the problem was, that my images had a white background, which is color value 255 and so **there was added a black border** which results in a **large color gradient**.

Maybe this thought can help others even if its almost a year later...

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, this [link](https://github.com/antonilo/TensBlur) points to a small project that uses `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d` to avoid the problem with the edges.